# Does the flags are for moderator attention?

Tags: discussion, flags

When I click the flag button to flagging a question or an answer it show many option to flag like this questions

[image]

And this for answers:

[image]

Then my question is here if these are flags for mod review why one option says:

**"other (Needs ♦ moderator attention)"**

If these flags are need for Mod review then why extra option for them(♦)?

I found on [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) about that but I see different options inside Mod attention from here that says only "not an answer", "low quality" and "other" options are for Mod attention.
If these options ON AU are for Mod why they are become a review queue in low quality and close votes queue and other queue? If need I open a new question about "How works review queue?"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone/everyone can review the "Not an Answer" and "Low Quality" flags. Spam and maybe Offensive are for 10k+ and ♦ mods. The "other" flag is only for the community (♦) moderators.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat actually the moderators queue always have all the flags, except duplicates/close. VLQ and NAA flags are fed to the Low quality review queue and close/duplicates flags are fed to the Close Votes queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If these flags are need for Mod review then why extra option for them(♦)?

Because, sometimes what you want to say to moderators isn't listed in the predefined options, so you have a 500 long message with the moderators.

> If these options ON AU are for Mod why they are become a review queue in low quality and close votes queue and other queue?

There are flags that goes to the Moderators only queue, and others can be dealt with without the intervention of the moderators, like the Close and Duplicate flags which are [fed to the Close Votes queue.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187008/213575)

> If need I open a new question about "How works review queue?"

I don't know what you are asking here... "How works review queue" isn't syntactically correct.

Comment: @KasiyA no, just ignore the ♦, everything is for ♦. The last chouce there is just so you can choose a different message. All flags go to the moderators (some also go into the review system) but only that last option lets you give the mods a personal message.

Comment: @terdon err... VTC doesn't go to the mod queue, AFAIK.

Comment: @Braiam ah, yes, true. I was thinking of the other flags since KasiA has the rep to VTC directly and wouldn't need to flag for it.